# How do I get a drawer to appear above the rest of my web page, so that the underlying elements are not seen and clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page that has a drawer. When I click the hamburger, a drawer slides out with menu items. However, the underlying web elements are still visible and clickable. I want them not to be seen or clickable. Here is my code for the drawer:

```
<nav id="drawer" class="nav">
      <div id="drawer-hamburger" class="box">
        <a id="menu2">
          <img class="menu-item" src="./images/threelines.png" alt="hamburger">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
        <a href="./home.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/account_blue.png" alt="Home Icon"></a>         
        <p><a href="./account.html">Account</a></p>          
      </div>
      <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
          <a href="./browse.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/browse_blue.png" alt="Settings Icon"></a>
          <p><a href="./browse.html">Browse</a></p>
      </div>
      <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">            
          <a href="./settings.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/settings_blue.png" alt="Browse Icon"></a>
          <p><a href="./settings.html">Settings</a></p>
      </div>
      <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
          <a href="./history.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/history_blue.png" alt="History Icon"></a>
          <p><a href="./history.html">Orders</a></p>            
      </div> 
    </nav>        
    <div id="main" class="box text-left">
      <a id="menu">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M2 6h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2z"/>
        </svg>
      </a>          
    </div>
```

And this is the corresponding css:

```
    nav {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* This trasform moves the drawer off canvas. */
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0);
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  /* Optionally, we animate the drawer. */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  opacity:1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 3;

}
nav.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "the underlying web elements are still visible and clickable"you are referring to #main so I made that area hidden and unclickable when the user toggle the nav.

```js
$(function(){
  $("nav").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("open")
    $("#main").toggleClass("hide")
  })
})
```

```css
nav {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* This trasform moves the drawer off canvas. */
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 0);
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  /* Optionally, we animate the drawer. */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  opacity:1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 3;

}
nav.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10px, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <nav id="drawer" class="nav">
       <div id="drawer-hamburger" class="box">
         <a id="menu2">
           <img class="menu-item" src="./images/threelines.png" alt="hamburger">
         </a>
       </div>
       <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
         <a href="./home.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/account_blue.png" alt="Home Icon"></a>         
         <p><a href="./account.html">Account</a></p>          
       </div>
       <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
           <a href="./browse.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/browse_blue.png" alt="Settings Icon"></a>
           <p><a href="./browse.html">Browse</a></p>
       </div>
       <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">            
           <a href="./settings.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/settings_blue.png" alt="Browse Icon"></a>
           <p><a href="./settings.html">Settings</a></p>
       </div>
       <div id="drawer-item" class="box text-center">
           <a href="./history.html"><img class="menu-item" src="./images/history_blue.png" alt="History Icon"></a>
           <p><a href="./history.html">Orders</a></p>            
       </div> 
     </nav>        
     <div id="main" class="box text-left">
       <a id="menu">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
           <path d="M2 6h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2z"/>
         </svg>
       </a>          
     </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack I appreciate the help!